# preg_replace_callback: regular expression search and replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, replace, preg-replace-callback

```
$details = "text...[book=123]...text...";

$details = preg_replace_callback(
  "/\[book=(.+?)\]/smi",
  function ($m) {
      global $skip_books;
      $book = $m[1];  // 123
      $feed = $m[2];  // 456       
  return "<div id=\"view_book_".$book."_".$feed."\"></div>";
  },
  $details
);
```

With this pattern i can only get $book ($m[1]):

```
"/\[book=(.+?)\]/smi"`
```

But i want to get $feed ($m[2]) too, so i replace to this [book=123_456].

How to get "456" ($m[2]) after the underline?

```
"/\[book=(.+?)_(.+?)\]/smi" ???
```

Comment: Please don't start your question with code, start with a short explanation what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: In your code, you don't show what/where the feed is in `$details`.  And your option you put at the end would work with `[book=123_456]`, though you want to be as specific as possible in your regex as well, so if there are only numbers, replace `(.+?)` with `([0-9]+)`

Comment: @fab IS THIS REALLY A MATTER?? You should give me a hand to solve my problem. Not focus on the format of question and down vote me because of this!

Comment: YES IT IS AND PLEASE DO NOT YELL IN THE LIBRARY

Comment: Mateys, stop yer infightin or I'll make ye walk the plank! =p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `global` here; you're already using a closure, so use the `use`:

```
function ($m) use ($skip_books) {
    // ...
}
```

*Btw, you're not actually using `$skip_books` in the code you've shown so far, but I'm assuming that's because you've simplified it*

If your arguments are always numbers, don't use something generic like `(.+?)` but be specific (the more the better):

```
/\[book=(\d+)_(\d+)\]/i
```

I've also removed the `/s` and `/m` modifiers, which are useless here.